# Groupby year and month for a column without having indexes in the output

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with dates and avarage tempratures
I want to groupby year and month on AVG_TEMP column.

data:

```
           DATE      AVG_TEMP
912     1957-07-01     22.2
913     1957-07-02     26.1
914     1957-07-03     25.6
            .
            .
            .

23249   2020-12-30     16.7
23250   2020-12-31     15.6
```

When I do

```
pd.DataFrame(data.groupby([data['DATE'].dt.year, data['DATE'].dt.month])['AVG_TEMP'])
```

The output contain the index among with the AVG_TEMP.

```
           0                          1
                           
0      (1957, 7)         912 22.2 913 26.1 914 25.6 915 26....
1      (1957, 8)         943 28.3 944 28.9 945 28.9 946 27....
                    .
                    .
                    .
698   (2020, 11)         23190 17.2 23191 16.7 23192 17.8 2319...
699   (2020, 12)         23220 12.2 23221 13.3 23222 13.9 2322...
```

As you can see exept from the AVG_TEMP it returns the index of the row as well.(below I cold the indexes to make it clear).

**912** 22.2 **913** 26.1 **914** 25.6 **915** 26....

**943** 28.3 **944** 28.9 **945** 28.9 **946** 27....

**23190** 17.2 **23191** 16.7 **23192** 17.8 **2319**...

I used as_index=False but the output is worse.

```
pd.DataFrame(new_data.groupby([new_data.DATE.dt.year, new_data.DATE.dt.month], as_index=False))
```

The outeput:

```
           0                              1
                           
0      (1957, 7)        DATE TAVG 912 22.2 913 26.1 914 25.6 915 26....
1      (1957, 8)        DATE TAVG 943 1957-08-01 28.3 944 ...
                   .
                   .
                   .
```

I try to explain it as much as I can because I can't make my code more reproducible.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe containing your expected output? It really would make 100x easier to help fast :)

Comment: what do you want to do with the values of `AVG_TEMP` for a given (year, month)? sum then or take the average, max or min?

Comment: Hi @ArgyGr, did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass `list` when calling [aggregate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate) on the `DataFrameGroupBy` object.

Here is an toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np  # just to create some random values

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["one", "one", "two", "three", "two", "two", "one", "three"],
        "B": np.random.randn(8),
    }
)

df.groupby("A").agg(list)

#                                                       B
# A                                                       
# one    [-0.38149367708676907, -0.5909611421048793, 2....
# three            [2.596225710326822, 0.4576674264970426]
# two    [-0.2581723789437292, 0.8189484792083834, -0.6...
```

In your case this would probably then look like this:

```
data.groupby([data['DATE'].dt.year, data['DATE'].dt.month]).agg(list)['AVG_TEMP']
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're looking for an answer that doesn't also group all the data into one column.

I think you could simply do this

```
data.groupby([data['DATE'].dt.year, data['DATE'].dt.month])['AVG_TEMP']
```

Or if you want to view the output of the operation

```
group = data.groupby([data['DATE'].dt.year, data['DATE'].dt.month])['AVG_TEMP']
group.apply(print)
```

Does this solve the problem?